# How to setup a WLAN interfaces with one for Hotspot?

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, wifi-hotspot, interface

So I'm trying to setup a two interfaces for two wireless cards. One card for connecting to wireless network an one for a hotspot to access this computer through SSH. I need wlan0 for WI-FI connection and wlan1 for `hostapd` hotspot.

I was trying to do it myself but I don't have enough information for this yet.
So my `/etc/network/interfaces` look like this:

```html
#/etc/network/interfaces
#Please use DietPi-Config to modify network settings.

# Local
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Ethernet
#allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
address 192.168.0.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
#dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

# Wifi
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
address 192.168.1.11
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
wireless-essid Zelkow177
wireless-key werabartekagataS
wireless-mode Managed
wireless-power off
wpa-ssid Zelkow177
wpa-psk werabartekagataS
#dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

#Wifi 2

auto wlan1
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet dhcp
#dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

#Bridge
#Work in progress
```

And my `hostapd.conf` looks like this:

```html
### Wireless interface wlan1 ###
interface=wlan1

### Bridge br0 ###
#bridge=br0

### Driver ###
driver=nl80211

### Country code ###
country_code=PL

### SSID ###
ssid=DietPi

### Hideing SSID ###
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0

### WPA ### (WPA=1, WPA2=2, WPA_Both=3)
wpa=2

### WPA Password ###
wpa_passphrase=dietpi

### WPA accept cipher suites ###
wpa_pairwise=THIP CCMP

### WI-FI mode ###
hw_mode=g

### Channel ###
channel=1

### Auth system ###
auth_algs=2

### Mac whilelist ###
macaddr_acl=1

### MAC whilelist file ###
accept_mac_file=/etc/hostapd/hostapd.accept
```

I want to do a bridge `wlan0` to `wlan1` to get access to internet while connected to hotspot and also DHCP but this isn't a problem.

But the main issue is that the `hostapd` don't work with wlan1 and the `br0` (that I deleted because it was horrible) don't work. Also I wan't to switch cards with interfaces because on the "bad" one currently work on `wlan0` but I want it to work on `wlan1` and same thing on the "better" one.

Cards that I'm using:

- For HOTSPOT TP-LINK TL-WN725N
- For WI-FI TPLINK TL-WN722N

I think I give all information needed but if not just ask for it.

## EDIT:

I did everything by myself! yey!
But this TP-LINK TL-WN725N doesn't work with hostapd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily create a Hotspot using [`create_ap`](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap) .

Install `create_ap` and run the following command:

```
create_ap wlan0 wlan1 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

`wlan0` to get an internet connection

`wlan1` to create a hotspot wifi

To install `create_ap` and starting the service , run:

```
git clone https://github.com/oblique/create_ap
cd create_ap
make install
systemctl start create_ap
systemctl enable create_ap
```